# Does enabling Reverse Path Filtering slows down network?

Tags: networking, routing, kernel

I am studying about Reverse Path Filtering (RPF) from this [document](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.kernel.rpf.html). My understanding on Reverse Path Filtering (RPF) is that it checks for every request and see whether the source address is routable through the interface from where the request came. Since there is always a checking that source address is routable or not, will enabling Reverse Path Filtering slows down the network?

Comment: What is this in reference to? It's unclear what you are asking and in what context.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart, I have modified the question with more details.